# Are nltk.corpus.wordnet and nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet different?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I'm looking at a [G4G page about wordnet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nlp-synsets-for-a-word-in-wordnet/), and see `from nltk.corpus import wordnet`. So I'm trying things out, but want to look at the documentation and see the methods etc. available, but can't seem to find `nltk.corpus.wordnet`, only `nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet`.

Then, I tried:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as WD1
from nltk.corpus.reader import wordnet as WD2

print(WD1 == WD2)
print(WD1 is WD2)
```

and got:

```
False
False
```

Could someone help me navigate nltk/wordnet's structure?

Comment: If you examine the types of WD1 and WD2 you will see that they are completely different objects

Answer (score 1):

`WD1` is instance of `nltk.corpus.util.LazyCorpusLoader` that  transform itself into `WD2.WordNetCorpusReader` after the first time it accessed :

```py
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as WD1
from nltk.corpus.reader import wordnet as WD2


# download wordnet
#import nltk
#nltk.download('wordnet')

print("Before : ", type(WD1)) # LazyCorpusLoader
synsets = WD1.synsets('example')
print("After : ", type(WD1))

print(isinstance(WD1, WD2.WordNetCorpusReader))
```

output:

```
Before :  <class 'nltk.corpus.util.LazyCorpusLoader'>
After :  <class 'nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.WordNetCorpusReader'>
True
```

The `nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet` is an interface for WordNet that contain readers and related tools for  `WordNet`.

When import `wordnet` from  `nltk.corpus` it automatically create instance of  a [LazyCorpusLoader](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.util.html#nltk.corpus.util.LazyCorpusLoader) then it transform itself to `WordNetCorpusReader` reader instances that can be used to access the `WordNet`.

You can find the documentation for  `nltk.corpus.wordnet` in [Sample usage for wordnet](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html)